# Returning a list of objects asynchronously

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous

I am trying to loop through a result set, run a query to retrieve data, and then add that data to a list and return it.

The problem is, I am trying to do this asynchronously and I am getting the error:

> 'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   does not contain a definition for 'ToListAsync' and the best extension
>   method overload
>   'System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.ToListAsync(System.Linq.IQueryable)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Here is the code for the method:

```
public async Task<List<IHFData>> GetHFServiceData(string wtTransfereeId)
{
    var hfDataList = new List<HFData>();

    Parallel.ForEach(aauthorizationList, item =>
    {
        // code to retrieve data from database (truncated)
        HFData hfData = Db.hfAuthorizations.AsNoTracking()....SingleOrDefault();

        hfDataList.Add(hfData);
    }

    return await hfDataList.ToListAsync(); // errors on this line
}
```

How can I build and return my list asynchronously?

Comment: It seems that `ToListAsync` is an [Entity Framework method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn220261(v=vs.113).aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few HUGE problems with your code.

First, you are calling `hfDataList.Add` inside of the `Parallel.ForEach`, `List<T>` is not thread safe, you can not call Add without locking.

Second as the error is telling you `ToListAsync` can only be called on a type that has the interface `IQueryable<T>`, you are calling it on a `List<T>` which does not implement that interface.

The correct way to do your query would be

```
public Task<List<IHFData>> GetHFServiceData(string wtTransfereeId)
{
    return Db.hfAuthorizations.AsNoTracking()....ToListAsync()
}
```

You will need to modify whatever was in the `....` that you took out to return a set of results instead of one result at a time.

Also the `await` was unnecessary, it was the last line in your function, you can just return the Task `directly` and simplify the generated code and reduce the overhead.

---

If you can't change it to a set query (and you should really try to, it will greatly improve your performance) then the way to do it your old way is to drop the parallel (Entity framework can't handle it either) and just do a normal foreach loop, then await on the async version of SingleOrDefault

```
public async Task<List<IHFData>> GetHFServiceData(string wtTransfereeId)
{
    var hfDataList = new List<HFData>();

    foreach(var item in aauthorizationList)
    {
        // code to retrieve data from database (truncated)
        HFData hfData = await Db.hfAuthorizations.AsNoTracking()....SingleOrDefaultAsync(); //This method is now async.

        hfDataList.Add(hfData);
    }

    //just return the list when you are done.
    return hfDataList; 
}
```

Comment: Yes,  I know it would be easier to just have one linq query and call ToListAsync(); however, the reason we are using a foreach is because it is too complex for one query.  Is it possible to use a foreach to build and return a list async?

Comment: @user1477388 I have updated the answer showing how to do it closer to how your old way would do it.

Comment: Question about this:  When debugging, it looks like the code hits the foreach loop then just goes straight to the return line, thus the `hfDataList` is always empty.  Do you have any idea why it would skip the async/add code?

Comment: @user1477388 Are you sure `aauthorizationList` is not empty? From what you are describing it sounds like it is.

Answer (score 5):

As the error message is telling you, there is no method of `List` to create a list asynchronously.  You already have a list at that point anyway.

It's also not safe to add items to a list from multiple threads, as you're doing from your parallel foreach loop.

You also shouldn't be executing a database query for every single item in your collection in the first place.  Instead you should be executing a *single* database query that fetches all of the items you need based on the information in the list that you have.  That query should end in a call to `ToListAsync`.

There is also no need to have an `async` method here, you can simply return the result of `ToListAsync` directly.